# Android offline maps with pre-installed (on apk file) tiles

Tags: android, maps, offline, osmdroid

Is there a way to have an offline map without the need of first time network connection in order to cache some map data?

First I used Google maps but it seems that it only caches some of the tiles and it does not load anything the first time launch if you do not have internet connection

After that I tried osmdroid where it is close enough to google maps logic but I can't find a way to use it with assets folder and not with sdk folder pre-installed tiles. What if users tablet hasn't got an sdcard? 
I do need a global solution that will work on any tablet.

I need only the tiles for a country not the whole world!

Here is my code so far

```
  MapView mapView = new MapView(this, 256); //constructor

    mapView.setClickable(true);

    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.DEFAULT_TILE_SOURCE);

    setContentView(mapView); //displaying the MapView

    mapView.getController().setZoom(6); //set initial zoom-level, depends on your need

    mapView.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(37.9513589,23.6474895)); //This point is in Enschede, Netherlands. You should select a point in your map or get it from user's location.

    mapView.setUseDataConnection(false);
```

and I have my tiles on assets/MapQuest/z/x/y.jpg

The weird is that in that link: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Map-Sources it says that:

> The Tile Source determines what imagery set is displayed, such as Bing, Mapquest, Mapnik, etc. The default Tile Provider, searches the following for your Tile Source, Assets, Offline zip/sqlite/etc in (/sdcard/osmdroid), Downloaded tile cache (/sdcard/osmdroid/tiles) and then finally the downloader.

Comment: A global solution without downloading maps? So you want to bundle the whole world with your app? That app is going to be huge... 10-20 GB if you use the OsmAnd databases...

Comment: I edited my question. Sorry for not defined it earlier

Comment: Have you read this: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Offline-Map-Tiles

Comment: No but all the instructions lead to the following "Copy the output file to /sdcard/osmdroid/". What if user has no sdcard?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Two strategies

1. Prepare a sqlite file just like described in the wiki and place it in assets. When your app first starts, copy the database to the /sdcard/osmdroid/ before the map is recreated/inflated
2. Store the contents of a tile zip in assets. The file structure would look like assets/TILESOURCENAME/Z/X/Y.extension. Using this mechanism, osmdroid droid should find it using the default tile provider chain.

Note: #1 is usually faster.

Comment: I would like to avoid depending on the sdcard as I mentioned so do you think that using the second approach will solve my problem by acessing instantly the assets folder and not copying to the sdcard?

Comment: I am using mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.DEFAULT_TILE_SOURCE); as you suggested, centering on the location of my tiles and zooming at the zoom level my tiles support. I have tiles in assets/tiles/z/x/y but nothing shows up!

Comment: sdcard in this context is not nessasaraly a real sdcard.

Comment: osmdroid uses a default location to lookup for the tiles: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+"osmdroid. You need to place your tiles there. As @Ifor said, doesn't necessarily mean a physical sdcard